# Python pass instance of itself as an argument to another function

Tags: python

I have a UserModel class that will essentially do everything like login and update things.

I'm trying to pass the instance of itself (the full class) as an argument to another function of another class.

For example: (obviously not the code, but you get the idea)

```
from Car import CarFactory

class UserModel:
    def __init__(self,username):
        self.username = username

    def settings(self,colour,age,height):
        return {'colour':colour,'age':age,'height':height}

    def updateCar(self,car_id):
        c = CarFactory(car_id, <<this UserModel instance>>)
```

So, as you can see from the very last line above I would like to pass an instance of UserModel to the CarData class, so when within the CarData class I can access the UserModel.settings(), however, I am unsure of the syntax. I could of course just do:

```
c = CarFactory(car_id,self.settings)
```

Any help would be grateful appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You need to mark the answer that solved your problem as accepted. This helps you gain trust on SO, so you can get better response. See the link @mgilson has provided in the comment in below answer.

Answer (score 13):

```
c = CarFactory(car_id, self)
```

doesnt work?

on a side note it would be `self.settings()` not `self.settings` ... unless you define settings to be a property